# How Options work in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Into the original httpd.conf, I have

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

I created a config file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ with

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.2:8009
<VirtualHost  192.168.0.2:8009>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/deve
    ServerName "deve:8009"
    ErrorLog /var/www/deve_errorlog
    CustomLog /var/www/deve_customlog common
    Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart the server and I still can see files in

```
http://192.168.0.2:8009/images
```

I tought that the more specific rule overides the general one

Where do I miss something ?

Comment: What if you visit http://deve:8009/images ?

Comment: Your `ServerName` should probably not have the :8009 portion, just the actual name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are basically correct, however missing a subtlety in the use of Options.

First, however, don't just stick them in the NameVirtualHost container, use a Directory Statement...

You are correct that the most specific ones apply, however, if an options statement contains a list of options where *every one* is prefixed with a + or -, then the options are merged with any existing options...

This means

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

is merged with

```
Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
```

to form

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI
```

Have a look at the apache documentation [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)

and specifically at the example:

> ...if the second Options directive uses the + and - symbols:

```
<Directory /web/docs>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory /web/docs/spec>
   Options +Includes -Indexes
</Directory>
```

> then the options FollowSymLinks and Includes are set for the `/web/docs/spec` directory.

Hence, the behaviour Apache is exhibiting with your configuration is correct.

I would just explicitly declare the options for the NameVirtualHost as follows:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/deve>
  Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
</Directory>
```